# Not all Stripe placeholders are visible in my screen at one time

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, placeholder

Hi I am trying to show all three placeholders at once in my screen and after I changed the placeholder name in stripe payment text field name **STPPaymentCardTextField**

I give the place holders names in story board like this

[image]

But when I run my program in simulator I get this output:

[image]

when ever I am trying to enter details those pick into text field then only it will show the place holder like

[image]

I want to show the placeholder card number replace of 4242424242424242 how to I resolve this issue.

```
  @IBOutlet weak var cardview: STPPaymentCardTextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.  
        cardview.numberPlaceholder = "CardNumber"
        cardview.cvcPlaceholder = "CVC"
        cardview.expirationPlaceholder = "MM/YY"
    }*
```

Comment: Do you want to replace "CardNumber" placeholder with "4242 4242 4242 4242.."?

Comment: I replace 424242424242424 to cardnumber

Comment: In second image it don't show card number placeholder how to I show that one with out user pick on text field also.

Comment: Do you also use instantiate STPPaymentCardTextField in viewDidLoad? If yes can you post some code for it?

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you don't need to set either in storyboard or in viewDidLoad custom placeholder for MM/YY and CVC because they are already default placeholders see code reference on [STPPaymentCardTextField.h](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/2f7ac6f87579b7748a1b792e3cd4b3d63d28bd8a/Stripe/PublicHeaders/STPPaymentCardTextField.h):

```
/**
 The placeholder for the expiration field. Defaults to @"MM/YY".
 */
@property (nonatomic, copy, nullable) IBInspectable NSString *expirationPlaceholder;

/**
 The placeholder for the cvc field. Defaults to @"CVC".
 */
@property (nonatomic, copy, nullable) IBInspectable NSString *cvcPlaceholder;
```

About your issue that you can't see all the three placeholders in one screen directly as [from the authors](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/issues/310):

> This is intentional. If you type a valid credit card number into the
>   CC field, it will slide away to reveal the expiration and CVC fields.

In bigger screens like iPad in Landscape mode those usually are all three visible at the same time as they can fit in the screen together.